# How can I transition from different column sizes?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, meteor, meteor-blaze

I look for a way to create transitions on a layout resizing dynamically (on hover of the different parts).

Here is my base layout with bootstrap:

```
<div class="page-container container" id="content">
        <div class="row" id="title_row">
            <div id="panel0" class="col-xs-12">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="panel1" class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
            <div id="panel2" class="col-xs-6">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="panel3" class="col-xs-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here it is in wire-frame:
[image]

I want to switch between 3 states as described in the pictures below:

state 1

[image]

---

State 2

[image]

---

State 3

[image]

I tried several approaches to solve that:

- I kept bootstrap layout system and only modified the columns sizes and order using javascript and spacebars helpers. [**Here is a Meteorpad version of it with no css based on `click` rather than `hover`**](http://meteorpad.com/pad/KqHWKyWeQQugDvzPw/My%20layout%20test) It works but I can't have any transition with this approach.
- I tried to use a CSS3 only approach, but it seems it would be complicated to make it responsive since CSS transitions need an absolute size value. I am not sure on that (> very weak in css) but I state it accordingly to [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3):

> “auto” height would of course be the best option here, but since we can’t animate to that, we need to set some heights for the transition

Additionally, I can't figure out how to obtain the 4 layouts responsively using CSS only, without bootstrap layout system. I don't know if it is even possible.

- Lastly, I took a look at `Blaze _uihooks`. The rationale would be to switch between 2 versions of each panel template and expand/reduce them accordingly during the transition. The event handling would be similar to the meteorPad example. This is my best lead so far, but I am clueless on where to start. Do you think this is a good way to go?

Before you tag the question as "too broad" or down-vote it, consider helping me narrowing it:

- Can it be done with CSS only or should I give up this option?
- Can it be done with `Blaze _uihooks`? If so, where should I start? I googled it, but I can't find any documentation or resource that helped. I found [packages](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-ui-hooks) but they are collection oriented or focused on route changes.
- Do you have any alternative ideas I should explore?